# Sveltekit socket.io not working on Node JS adapter

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io, sveltekit

I could use some help troubleshooting a [socket.io](https://socket.io) issue I'm having with sveltekit running node-adapter. This for a tool that is used to monitor network endpoints. The [socket.io](https://socket.io) is being used to embed and SSH xterm session within the web browser window. I am new to sveltekit and js frontend development, as I'm primarily a python developer. We had a dedicated team member working on this project, and he got it 85% complete before leaving and moving on to a new job. Due to budget restrictions, this project landed in my lap, so I'm learning on the job. The issue that I have, is that the [socket](https://socket.io) works perfectly when in "preview" mode, `vite preview`. But when I build the application, `vite build`, and host using `node .index.js`, I get `Error: Not found: /socket.io/`. This is being hosted behind an nginx proxy.

./svelte.config.js

```
import adapter from '@sveltejs/adapter-node';
import { vitePreprocess } from '@sveltejs/kit/vite';


/** @type {import('@sveltejs/kit').Config} */
const config = {
    // Consult https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/integrations#preprocessors
    // for more information about preprocessors
    preprocess: [
        vitePreprocess(),
    ],

    kit: {
        // adapter-auto only supports some environments, see https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/adapter-auto for a list.
        // If your environment is not supported or you settled on a specific environment, switch out the adapter.
        // See https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/adapters for more information about adapters.
        adapter: adapter(),
        csrf: {
            checkOrigin: false
        },
    }
};

export default config;
```

./vite.config.ts

```
import { createSocketServer } from './src/lib/webSocketConnection';
import { sveltekit } from '@sveltejs/kit/vite';
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        sveltekit(),
        {
            name: 'socket-io',
            configureServer(server) {
                createSocketServer(server)
            }
        }
    ]
});
```

./src/lib/webSocketConnection

```
import { Server } from "socket.io"
import type { Server as HttpServer } from 'http';
import { Client } from "ssh2";
import type { ConnectConfig } from "ssh2";
import type { Socket } from "socket.io-client";

export const createSocketServer = (server) => {
    const io = new Server(server.httpServer as HttpServer)

    interface Config extends ConnectConfig {
        totp: string
    }

    ...
}
```

+page.svelte

```
<script lang="ts">
    import type { Terminal } from 'xterm';
    import 'xterm/css/xterm.css';
    import { onMount } from 'svelte';
    import { page } from '$app/stores';
    import { io } from 'socket.io-client';
    import type { Socket } from 'socket.io-client';
    import { FitAddon } from 'xterm-addon-fit';
    import { Terminal as Xterm } from 'xterm';

    let terminal: Terminal;
    let socket: Socket;
    let termElement: HTMLElement;
    let fitAddon: FitAddon;

    const establishWebSocket = async () => {

        socket = io();

        socket.off('connect').on('connect', () => {
            socket.emit('connectSSH', sshInfo);
        });
        socket.off('data').on('data', (data) => {
            terminal.write(data);
        });
    };

    ...
</script>

<div id="term" class="flex-1 max-w-full max-h-[95%] overflow-hidden" bind:this={termElement} />

<style>
    .xterm-viewport {
        overflow-y: hidden;
    }
</style>
```

/etc/nginx/sites-available/site

```
server {
        listen 443;

        server_name fqdn;

        ssl_certificate           /etc/letsencrypt/live/fqdn/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key       /etc/letsencrypt/live/fqdn/privkey.pem;
        ssl on;
        ssl_session_cache  builtin:1000  shared:SSL:10m;
        ssl_protocols  TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!CAMELLIA:!DES:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Proto https;
                proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Host $remote_addr;
                proxy_read_timeout 14400s;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }
}
```

I have tried to change the webSocketConnection to use a generic server, but that didn't seem to work either, or I implemented it incorrectly.